# How can I disable future dates in angular p-calendar?

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using calendar input as follows.

```
<p-calendar  maxDate="dateTime" showTime="true" hourFormat="12" showButtonBar="true" [(ngModel)]="dateTime" name="timeOfUse" required #timeOfUse="ngModel">
          </p-calendar>
```

I want to disable future dates in this datepicker. It may be a simple property, but I can't figure it out. Appreciate any help

Comment: What is the angular version

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're not so far ! Just add square brackets to `maxDate` and it will work :

```
<p-calendar  [maxDate]="dateTime" showTime="true" hourFormat="12" showButtonBar="true" [(ngModel)]="dateTime" name="timeOfUse" required #timeOfUse="ngModel">
</p-calendar>
```

And if you want to disable dates 3 days after today for instance :

```
export class AppComponent {

   dateTime = new Date();

   constructor() {
     this.dateTime.setDate(this.dateTime.getDate() + 3);    
   }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found this on web might help you,Read the topic **Disable specific dates and/or days**

Date Restriction

```
[maxDate]="maxDateValue"
```

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

Reference

https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=49578